# ETIMEDOUT on Azure Service Bus with amqp

Tags: node.js, azure, amqp, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are using the amqp10 package for nodejs to receive messages from a queue on azure's service bus. We are sometimes getting an error

```
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11) at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:615:25) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
```

but this is thrown around 12 minutes after it stops receiving messages. Is there a way to configure the timeout? We're using the provided service bus policy `Policy.ServiceBusQueue`.

The code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/njLT/6856ae5090c688590747f8181333b84f)

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a longer timeout with:

```
client.connect(uri, { idleTimeout: 120000 }).then(() => {
    // ...
})
```

The [default value of idleTimeout](https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10/blob/0cfea954b7d14b361dfe11a06d6ce19b714b2b35/lib/constants.js#L19) is 120000 milliseconds.

Comment: shouldn't I be trying to reduce the timeout if I want it to reconnect earlier? I'm not sure why there is a delay of over 12 minutes before the error is thrown in the first place

Comment: 120,000ms is 120 seconds - 2 minutes. Not 12 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `subscribe` method that is offered in version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK if you want to receive the messages **forever**(you can stop receiving as needed).

It also handles the disconnects and reconnections gracefully and is capable of recovering even from fatal errors such as entity-not-found.

You can refer to the [receiveMessagesStreaming.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/typescript/src/receiveMessagesStreaming.ts) sample code that uses version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK.

I know this is a late reply, but just in case someone is running into issues with the older service-bus node SDK and landed here, refer to the links below.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` has been released recently.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)